# Dataset from SQL Query Won't Return Time of 00:00

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am working on a web application in VB.net 2008 with a SQL 2008R2 database on the back end.  I am sending a query to SQL through VB to obtain a patient's hospital visit information:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM visit WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE visit_code = '123' AND start_date <= '07/17/2012' ORDER BY visit_code DESC, start_date DESC
```

This returns the correct record.  However, there is a hold_start_date_time field defined as datetime in the database which contains both the date and time.  Everything works great unless the time is midnight - 00:00.

When I run the above query directly in SQL Server Management Studio the field displays correctly.  But in the dataset in VB.NET when I look at the datarow the field has only the date with no time at all.  A time of anything other than 00:00 populates the dataset correctly.

Unfortunately, midnight is a perfectly valid time for this field.  Is there a way I can get it to appear in the dataset?

```
Dim dsData as DataSet
dsData = GetDataSet(strSql, "visit")

If DataSetRowCount(dsData, "visit") > 0 Then
    Dim drData As DataRow
    drData = dsData.Tables("visit").Rows(0)
End If


Public Overloads Function GetDataSet(ByVal strSQL As String, ByVal srcTable As String) As DataSet
Dim daData As SqlDataAdapter

daData = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, strConnectionString)
daData.Fill(dsData, srcTable)

daData.Dispose()
daData = Nothing

Return dsData
End Function
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you say "I look at the datarow the field has only the date with no time at all", what type is this field in the DataTable ? And how do you inspect it ?

Comment: Sorry - I updated the code to make it more clear.  I am not explicitly defining the datatable, just taking whatever SQL sends back and naming the table "visit".  In debug I have a watch window and when it hits the drData line I can see all of the values of that record.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the time is there, just not showing up because the visualizer tool (VS Debugger?) don't show if it's 00:00. Try dump in the HTML or window with proper formatting and you will be fine.

Comment: The issue arose because another function is bombing out because the time is Nothing.  I traced it back to the above function.  The time is definitely not there.

Comment: How are you getting the time part from the DateTime?

Comment: I'm using the Fill method of SqlDataAdapter to populate the dataset.  I then check the length of the hold_start_date_time value in the datatable/datarow.  If it is greater than 10 I pull just the time value to a variable.  But that line of code never gets hit, because the length of hold_start_date_time is 10.
I can manually work around this to check if the date value is present but the time value is not, but I believe that the SqlDataAdapter should be pulling the value, even if it's 00:00.

Comment: Why don't you use `value.ToShortTimeString()`?

Comment: The problem is that the time isn't present in VB if it's 00:00 in SQL.  If the time is anything else everything works perfectly.  The problem is occurring in the Fill method of the SqlDataAdapter.  I don't want to explicitly define the datatable structure in case there are changes to the SQL table in the future.

Comment: Eduardo is right... The debugger does not show the time information on a datetime, but that does not mean the information is not there...

Comment: Even aside from debug, the value is not getting passed to the variable meant to hold it because the total length of the field is 10.  It contains only the date.

Comment: what variable type are you using on the SQL Server? What SQL are you using to retrieve the datetime? If it isn't a one of the date types it could be that the program that stored the data didn't store the time portion. if that is the case, and you can assume a missing time is always 00:00 then adjust the value when you get it. Or create a query for the server that always returns the time.

Comment: What type of variable are you using to store the value? Is it a `DateTime`? If it's `DateTime`, then by it's definition it will always hold a date and a time value (i.e. it will be impossible to create a variable that will just hold a time value **or** to create a variable that will just hold a date value)